# Content Structure using Playa and Matrix

Tags: matrix, playa

I have the following relationship that I am trying to model in EE using Playa and Matrix plugins:

Song List (has many Songs)
-> Song (has many arrangements)
  -> Arrangement (P&T asset field) - points to a .pdf in the file system

The idea is that the end user should be able to create a Song list that is composed of Songs, and each song can be represented by a number of Arrangements, each of which is an asset in the file system, represented by an P&T Asset.

My desire is that the back end user is able to create a song list by selecting a Song from a drop down list, and then select an arrangement based on the Song title. The user should be able to add multiple songs to the list.

I’m having trouble creating this in EE with Playa and Matrix.  Any thoughts on how I can do this?